# Constraint layout with wrap_content clips it's content

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Recently I've bumped into a strange `ConstraintLayout` behavior. What I tried to do was a simple layout with `ImageView`, `Button` and a `TextView`. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:text="TEST TEXT"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/marginSpacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/marginSpacer" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `ImageView` content is loaded using Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(this).load("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png").into(imageView);
```

Here is how I wanted it to look like:

[image]

And here's what I actually got:

[image]

My intent was to make the text align relative to the button, not the image, how do I make this happen? Why did the `ConstraintLayout` clip itself to the `ImageView`? On the other hand, if I align the text relative to the image everything works great and nothing is clipped. 
The full source is available here:
https://github.com/satorikomeiji/ConstraintLayoutBug

Answer (score 2):

Use this for your Button:

> @+id/button

instead of

```
android:id="@id/button"
```

You'll be able to design urself.
I would suggest you to add loading image:
`.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_error_black_48px)`

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="TEST TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonLayout" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummyView" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to align something to the bottom of the parent

Align `TEST TEXT` TextView bottom to the bottom of parent like this:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:text="TEST TEXT"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
```

And add plus sign in button id

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/marginSpacer" />
```

Comment: Have you added plus sign...because it worked after adding plus in button id

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="TEST TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ButtonLayout" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummyView" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution is not suitable for me because the image can be of varying height, and I want the button to be attached to the **bottom** of the image not with the hardcoded margin from the top.

Comment: @satorikomeiji sorry for the delay. Please check my updated answer. hope it helps.